# Spring Boot / RabbitMQ different content_type with Jackson2JsonMessageConverter

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, http-message-converter

I have a usecase where a service consumes different RabbitMQ queues.

- On one of the queues there is JSON encoded data, where the content_type header is set to 
  `application/json`
- There is a second queue, where binary data is being consumed, content_type is `application/octet-stream`

In the configuration there is a MessageConverter defined:

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}
```

Consuming methods are declared like that:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "rpc-device-cmd")
public byte[] rpcCommand(byte[] request) throws IOException, ConfigurationException { .... }
```

My issue is that Jackson2JsonMessageConverter complains about the `application/octet-stream` header ( 
`Could not convert incoming message with content-type application/octet-stream 'json' keyword missing.`) and even worse, it is encoding the byte[] response of the method above to JSON and base64.

Question:
How is it possible to make sure that the JSON converter does not touch my byte[] responses and ignores messages with a "non-json" content_type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You achieve this by creating your own MessageConverter implementation to handle the rabbitMQ response string like as shown in the below example

https://github.com/nidhishkrishnan/messaging - here I have demonstrated how we can marshall and convert the RabbitMQ message string to Java domain object based on the binding key using MessageConverter

[image]

In your case you can retrieve the content-type from your message to marshal the output as per your requirement

```
String contentType = message.getMessageProperties().getContentType();
```